VHDL signal not assigned in every case statement
If I have a the following case statement in a VHDL code
case state is
    when ST_STATE1 =>
        a <= '1';
    when ST_STATE2 => 
        b <= '1';
    when ST_STATE3 =>
        a <= '0';
        b <= '0';
end case;

Given that a and b are correctly initialized and defined at reset. I understand that there will be a latch for b in ST_STATE1 and a latch for a in ST_STATE2, but is this something bad? The expected behavior would be the one of
case state is
    when ST_STATE1 =>
        a <= '1';
        b <= b;
    when ST_STATE2 => 
        a <= a;
        b <= '1';
    when ST_STATE3 =>
        a <= '0';
        b <= '0';
end case;

but if there are much more signals, and much more possible states I prefer to only list the signals that actually have to change. Will the synthesizer always generate the code equal to the second snippet?

Inferring latches is not defined in the VHDL language but finds its roots in IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis  (withdrawn due to lack of vendor participation) wherein you’d find that identity assignments have no bearing on determining the inference of a latch. 6.2.1.1 Level-sensitive storage from process with sensitivity list “By default, the effect of an identity assignment of the signal (or variable) shall be as though the assignment was not present.”

This question may be an example of the lack of sufficient research including the use of a [mcve] which would have demonstrated the two case statements were equivalent.

Not sure if I agree, I did my research but couldn't find a clear answer, at least to my understanding and I think the result of an MRE is very vendor specific. As mentioned I do it like the above more or less all the time to keep the code readable and never had an issue, I just wanted to confirm that this is not any general concept of the VHDL language and apparently (according to your first comment) it's not treated the same by all vendors or at least they do not agree on a general solution.

Do you really want a latch? in most instances, in FPGAs, latches are considered bad and will go against pretty much every company's design rules. Do you explicitly want a latch? the issue with latches is they are difficult to time and prone to glitches.. do you reeally want this? usually, its the case that latches need to be explicity written, explained and excepted for, and go through a thorough design review, because they will not work in the standard timing tools etc. Usually its easier just to clock the circuit.

Sorry, this case statement is clocked of course. And I think the design tool doesn't create a latch for these signals, at least it doesn't report them. I'd really expect it to generate the same logic for both snippets.

A clocked process will not create a latch. It will simply infer a register with a clock enable if a signal is not assigned in all branches.

To summarize the comments and to answer your 2 questions:

"I understand that there will be a latch for b in ST_STATE1 and a latch for a in ST_STATE2, but is this something bad?"

There is no construct as "a latch (or flipflop) for b in ST_STATE1" but as your code is inside a clocked process (as you mention in your comment) there will be a flipflop for signal b which will be set to the specified values in state ST_STATE2 and ST_STATE3 and will keep its value in state ST_STATE1. The same is true for signal a.
And there is nothing "bad" with both code snippets. I prefer the first one, but sometimes for better readability I have also used the second one.

"Will the synthesizer always generate the code equal to the second snippet?"

Yes, it will.

There is no clocked process shown in the question.
